# Checking if topological ordering of one graph is maintained in another

Tags: algorithm, graph, topological-sort

If I have a set of nodes `N` and a set of vertices `V_1` that define a graph `G_1` with a certain topological order, how can I check whether a subset of nodes from `N` and a new set of vertices `V_2` that define a graph `G_2` maintain the topological order of `G_1`?

e.g.

```
G_1: 

D -> E
B -> C
A -> C
```

A topological ordering of `G_1`: `[A, B, C, D, E]`

```
G_2:

D -> B
B -> E
```

The topological ordering of `G_2`: `[D, B, E]`

I was thinking of some sort of brute force approach where I generate all topological orderings of `G_1`, remove the nodes not found in `G_2` from those orderings and check if any match the first ordering found of `G_2`.

Is my potential solution correct? Do you have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is correct, but it's inefficient.

For some bad cases (G_2 is a cycle so there's no topological ordering and G_1 has no edges so any ordering is topological) you end up doing O(N!*N).

A better solution is to compute a topological order that satisfies both graphs.

In the standard topological sort algorithm you keep count of incoming edges. At each step you pick a node that has a count of 0, add it to the solution, decrease the count for all outgoing edges and continue until either there's no more nodes to pick or all have non-zero count (a cycle).

What I suggest is that you keep two sets of counts for the two graphs. Pick a node that has a count of 0 in both sets (that is, is a valid next choice in both graphs) and update the counts in both graphs according to their outgoing links.
If you finish all the nodes then you've found a ordering that is a topological sort for both graphs, otherwise there's no such ordering.

If you can, you can also merge the two graphs and compute a topological sort on the merged graph using the standard algorithm. The result (if any) should be a valid topological sort for both original graphs.

Both solutions (if implemented correctly) will have a complexity of O(N).

Comment: Regarding the reasoning behind the second solution: Is it true because if `G_2` did not maintain the topological ordering of `G_1`, it would mean that `G_2` inverts the ordering of `G_1` in one way or another leading to a cycle when merging the graphs?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes. You can also show that the combined graph will generate a count table equivalent to the two we kept in the first version (assuming you count duplicate edges twice).